# Live, evolving, dynamic wallpaper (desktop) on a Mac

Tags: macos, desktop

Should it be possible to develop a dynamic desktop for the Mac? By "dynamic," I mean a desktop whose images take system parameters, such as the time and job information, and use this information to update the image. Information about image states would also be preserved between sessions. I'm not talking about a movie or a stochastic but autonomous screen saver. Is there any reason a user couldn't develop such a thing? (I'd like to ask how but am trying to keep the question constrained.)

I'm not new to programming but have no sense how Macs work. I'd like to know if there's some fatal flaw in my goal before I start digging in. Thanks in advance for any pointers.

**Update:** [Wikipedia implies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_wallpaper#In_Mac_OS_X) there's no direct way to do what I want to do--Mac desktop wallpaper must come from a folder of static images or a screen saver. The only viable approach I see at the moment would be to generate images periodically for such a screen saver (e.g., [by adapting this Python script](http://www.tuaw.com/2008/04/06/a-dynamic-screen-saver-diy-style/)). If this is stupid or a slicker method might exist, would love to hear it.

Comment: I vaguely recall a program which displays a globe view of Earth and showing which portion is receiving sunlight.

Comment: It might have been [Blue Planet](http://blueplanetapp.com/) or a predecessor like [OSXPlanet](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/13521/osxplanet). I hadn't seen either before, and I can't tell how dynamic they are--but they give me some hope. Thanks.

Comment: Do post somewhere if you ever manage this! :)

Answer (score 0):

Very late response but I only stumbled across the question and noticed some recent interest...
Aren't you looking for something like [GeekTool](http://projects.tynsoe.org/en/geektool/) ?

Comment: And the new kid on the block appears to be [Ubersicht](http://tracesof.net/uebersicht/)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have been implemented in the latest version of Mac OS X: Mojave.

This article has some tips on how to make your own, towards the bottom: https://www.howtogeek.com/369645/download-more-dynamic-wallpapers-for-mojave-or-make-your-own/